# Duplicate background change for selected row in baseadapter when touched

Tags: android, listview, background, duplicates, baseadapter

im using baseadapter ang i'm trying to change the background of an item when it is clicked. but when i scroll down, other row's background is also changed. i've already specified my choicemode to single but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onfocus listener to complete view inside adapter like this.

```
 row.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocussed) {
if(isFocussed)
{
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else
{
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
}
```

});